# How to draw self contained boxes to express hierarchy

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw self contained boxes to express hierarchy? I would like to draw the following image, I know how to draw the small boxes (A,B,C) using Tikz:

```
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, text centered]
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
    \node [block, thick] (init) {initialize model};
    \node [block,thick, right of=init,node distance=3cm] (system) {system};
    \draw [->, ultra thick] (init) -- (system);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But I don't know how to draw the big boxes (System general & special).[image: snapshot]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You might try something like `\draw (0,0) rectangle (5,5)` (adjust to your needs). Please help us help you by providing a minimal compilable code example (MWE).

Comment: Thanks so much! But how do you specify the location of the text please?

Comment: Simply create another node (with `draw=none`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following code recreate image provided in your question:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                fit,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 8mm and 4mm,
 block/.style = {rectangle, draw, thick,
                 text width=12mm, align=center},
   FIT/.style = {rectangle, draw, thick, inner ysep=12mm, inner xsep=6mm,
                 fit=#1},
   arr/.style = {-Stealth, ultra thick},
         font = \sffamily\bfseries
                        ]
\node [block]               (a) {A};
\node [block,below=of a]    (b) {B};
\node [FIT=(a) (b)] (ssys) {};
    \node[below right=0mm of ssys.north west] {System special};
\node [block, below left=of ssys] (c) {C};
\node [FIT=(ssys) (c)] (gsys) {};
     \node[below right=0mm of gsys.north west] {System general};
%
\draw [arr] (c.north) -- (b.south);
\draw [arr] (b) -- (a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

in code i use `tikz` libraries `arrows.meta` (for arrows), `fit` (for nodes "system special" and "system general") and `positioning` for positioning of nodes in image.